# Is there any drawbacks of "accepting all cookies" while in incognito mode?

Tags: web-browser, cookies

Since the GDPR landed, many websites have to inform you about their cookie usage and give you an option to enable/disable them for provider and for reason of storage. Say that I find a link I want to read but they ask for consent of storing cookies in my device (which I would rather not, if possible)

Am I fine if I open a private/incognito window and accept all cookies there and close it after I'm done?

The reason behind this is because having to withdraw consent of all links I click quickly becomes a tedious task. Please also note that disabling cookies is not an option for two reasons: there are sites from which I want to store cookies and I intend to do this in all of my devices, not only in a specific system

Answer (score 3):

If the only concern you have is tracking cookies, the only downside I see is that cookies aren't cleared until you close the incognito session, so they could still be used to track you across sites during that session.

As an alternative, there are also browser extensions that clear cookies after leaving a site, but only for sites you haven't whitelisted.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I was looking for other things to worry about if there were any, besides of cookie tracking.

Comment: @mrbolichi the question only asked about cookies. Without knowing what you are worried about, it is hard to identify other issues.